# C# Monogame ContentManager, see content?

Tags: c#, monogame

is there a way to return/get a list of the content compiled in Monogame's Content Manager? or would you have to use system classes and do it that way?

what are your thoughts?

thanks :)

Comment: I have created service for that, which wraps ContentManager and puts all content in dictionary, so I can easily have a list of all loaded content. Maybe that would be a solution for you? Singleton class with dictionary

Comment: I will definitely look into it, thank you very much for a suggestion :D